# Why is the root of my hard drive acting like a picture folder?

Tags: windows-xp

I was browsing around and looking at some files in application data that my application saved (specifically screenshots) and I clicked the `Show the contents of this folder` or whatever it was to prevent someone who doesn't know *anything* about a computer from deleting an important file. However, I have a habit of clicking on the right the `Hide contents of this folder` when I was done to prevent other users from wiping the hard drive accidentally. This time, when I went to click the button, it wasn't there.

**What *was* there is the buttons like `get pictures from scanner or camera`, `veiw as a slide show`, etc. Why is this happening? How can I fix this?**

---

**EDIT:**

Here's what my C drive looks like:
[image: My C Drive]

It has those buttons and the image at the bottom like a picture folder (a folder where you put pictures in. Example:
[image: A Picture Folder]

This is what it should look like (this is program files, though. The root of the drive is the only thing affected.):
[image: What it should look like]

Here's the "warning message" I was talking about:
[image: Program Files Hidden]

Just for completeness, this is how you change what type of folder it is (doesn't work in important folders like My Documents, My Pictures, or root of C drive--but I wish it would.):
[image: Folder Properties]

---

**Sorry for any confusion I made.** Thank you.

Comment: Can you post screenshots? It's difficult to understand from your description what buttons you're talking about.

Comment: @Karan Sorry, I "got kicked off the computer for a few days." (A.K.A. Everybody else wanted to use it at the same time.) I edited it now. Do you think that clears it up enough to be reopened? If you do, please vote. If you don't understand it still, tell me.

Comment: It's clear now, voted to reopen. Do try starteleport's answer though; that's quite likely the correct solution. Show both hidden and system files and delete any Desktop.ini files from C:\

Comment: It's 2013. Time to upgrade to Windows 7 or 8.

Comment: @ta.speot.is It's also costly. And this isn't my computer. And the owner uses Ubuntu more than Windows (but I still want this enabled for protection.) Many people also love XP and it still works for them. Not to mention, there is 7,501 questions on SuperUser.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete `desktop.ini`, this may help. You may have to uncheck "Hide protected operating system files" in Folder Options to see it.

Answer (score -1):

In explorer, go to your C: root.  Right click in a clear area.  Select View.  Do you have something like Thumbnails selected as your view?  If so, it will assume the folder you are in contains images.  Choose something like icons as your view.